# How do you get the file type when a file is opened using the Python filedialog askopenfilename() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, file-type

I have this program written in python tkinter which opens a file using the tkinter filedialog askopenfilename() method. It will get the contents of that file and will insert that into a TextBox.

I want to be able to get the file type of that file (i.e if the file is a Python file then I want the console to print ".py" if its HTML then I want it to print ".html" and so forth).

So this is what I tried:

```
FilePath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/gui/", title="Open a File", filetypes=(("All Files", "*.*"), ("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("HTML Files", "*.html"), ("CSS Files", "*.css"),("JavaScript Files", "*.js"), ("Python Files", "*.py")))

print(FilePath)
```

However, this gives me:
/home/Test/RandomFolder/Test.py

Is it possible to get just the ".py" at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
open_File = easygui.fileopenbox(msg="Choose a file", default=r'C:\Users\user\*.txt')

extension = open_File.split('.', 1)

print(extension)
```

So what I've done here is get the users path, and because typically in a path you won't have a `.` anywhere unless its at the end of a file, I've split the string into 2, if you want the everything before the `.` just use `extension = open_File.split('.', 0)`, and everything after use the above code.

Also, although I am using Easygui in this case, it applies to any file dialog method, the principle is in regards to how you're getting what you want out of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.path.splitext()`:

```py
import os
...
FilePath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/gui/", title="Open a File", filetypes=(("All Files", "*.*"), ("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("HTML Files", "*.html"), ("CSS Files", "*.css"),("JavaScript Files", "*.js"), ("Python Files", "*.py")))

_, fext = os.path.splitext(FilePath)
print(fext)
```